# How to return respond result to function with Alamofire Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

I use Alamofire framework for doing read server json file and download it. I want to check the json last modified date and let user decieded to download json contents. But the function getLastModifiedDate always return nil. I list the sample code here.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var lastModifedDateLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (getLastModifiedDate() != nil) {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Download or NOT", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: .default, handler: {action in
                self.callDownload()
            }))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func getLastModifiedDate() -> String? {

        var date:String?

        Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com/apps/demopad/manifest.json")
            .response { serverResponse in
                date = serverResponse.response?.allHeaderFields["Last-Modified"] as? String
                print(date ?? "Server date is nil")
                self.lastModifedDateLabel.text = date
        }
        return date
    }

    func callDownload() {

        print("Call Download func")

        Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com/apps/demopad/manifest.json")
            .responseJSON { serverRespone in
                let jsonDict = serverRespone.result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any>
                print(jsonDict ?? "JSON data is nil")
        }
    }

}
```

[Running result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0U6r.png)

I am beginner of Swift 3 and network progamming, I google and saw Swift document no idea how to resolve this problem. Anyone can give help? Thank you very much.

Comment: closures have return type void. You can not return from closure ,use completion handler instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using closures that's why `getLastModifiedDate` returns nil because it's not returning `"Last-Modified"` value .You have to use closures if you are doing async task like this

```
func getLastModifiedDate(completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {

    var date:String?

    Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com/apps/demopad/manifest.json")
        .response { serverResponse in
            date = serverResponse.response?.allHeaderFields["Last-Modified"] as? String
            print(date ?? "Server date is nil")
            self.lastModifedDateLabel.text = date
          completion(date)

    }

}
```

Comment: Because I want to prompt alert view and user click OK, I will call a download json (callDowload) function. I plan the callDownload will also have return values, is it use closure in callDownload() too? Can I not use async mode to wait server return, then do next step? Is my concept wrong?

Comment: See, call download is performing server call hence you have to wait for it and hence you have to use completion handler to wait for response. So if you performing server calls then you have to use closures. Hope you got?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 func getLastModifiedDate() -> String? {

    var date:String?

    Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com/apps/demopad/manifest.json")
        .response {
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                print("Request failed with error: \(response.response?.statusCode)")

                if let response = JSON as? NSMutableDictionary
                {

                    date = response?.object(forKey: "Last-Modified") as! String

                    print(date ?? "Server date is nil")
                    self.lastModifedDateLabel.text = date
                }
                else if let response = JSON as? NSDictionary
                {

                    date = response?.object(forKey: "Last-Modified") as! String

                    print(date ?? "Server date is nil")
                    self.lastModifedDateLabel.text = date
                }
                else if JSON is NSArray
                {

                }

                break

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                callback(response.result.value as? NSMutableDictionary,error as NSError?)
                break
            }


        }
        .responseString { response in

            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
    }
 }
 return date
 }
```